# Indefinite integral not evaluated in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an Indefinite integral integral:

```
Rm = 50; d = 3; W = 1.2;
f = 1/(1 - R^2/Rm^2)
A = W*(d - 1 + X)/d*R^(X - 1) - R*f - (1 - d)/R;
B=W/d*R^X + 1;
Integrate[A/B, R]
```

Mathematica evaluate the above mentioned integral only for X = 0, 1 and 2 but not for the other non-integers values. (Note: for my problem X belong to [0,2].)
I have also evaluated this integral in Maple 11. Maple give results for all values of X. But I want these results in Mathematica.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 'inexact' floating point value of `W=1.2`. If you use `W=12/10` you get a result.  Note in this case you actually get a faster/cleaner result if you leave all the numeric values out except for `X` until after integration:

```
 Clear[d,W,Rm,X];
 f = 1/(1 - R^2/Rm^2);
 A = W*(d - 1 + X)/d*R^(X - 1) - R*f - (1 - d)/R;
 B = W/d*R^X + 1;
 Block[{X = 3}, 
     Simplify[Integrate[A/B, R] /. {d -> 3, W -> 1.2, Rm -> 50}]]
```

> 1.0627 ArcTan[0.57735 - 0.850791 R] - 0.05 ArcTanh[0.02 R] + 
>    2. Log[R] + 0.614458 Log[1.44225 + 1.06266 R] - 
>    5.*10^-7 Log[-2500. + R^2] - 
>    0.307229 Log[2.08008 - 1.53262 R + 1.12924 R^2] + 
>    1. Log[3. + 1.2 R^3]

Aside you really should avoid starting your own variable names with caps to avoid conflicts with built in symbols.